# How can I not escape a character sequence in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, resource-files

I am reading in a value from a resource file (.resx) in C# and in that value, I have added \r\n\r\n so that it gets displayed in the correct format. e.g. `blah\r\n\r\nblah`
For some reason, the string automatically adds a '\' so effectively text becomes `blah\\r\\n\\r\\nblah` and thus it escapes the character sequences.

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope this helps

Comment: Can you add that section of the code along with your question?

Comment: Where are you seeing “blah\\r\\n\\r\\nblah”? In the Visual Studio debugger? Do you see quotes `"` at the start and end of the string? That means you are looking at a C# literal which contains `blah\r\n\r\nblah` and does not contain quotes or backslashes. C# literals escape metacharacters so you can see them, otherwise they would be invisible.

Comment: I am seeing `blah\\r\\n\\r\\nblah` in the debugger and the output displays `blah\r\n\r\nblah`

Comment: Showing a sample of the actual expected output might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **Shift+Enter** to add a new line in .resx file instead of `\r\n`. Or replase like `str = str.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");`

Answer (score 0):

When you stored the string, the escape characters were stored as part of the string literal, and are no longer 'escaping' anything. One thing you could do is replace your placeholder string "\r\n" with a newline character after you read it.

For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var resourceStr = "blah\\r\\n\\r\\nblah";

    Console.WriteLine("Original resource string:");
    Console.WriteLine(resourceStr);

    Console.WriteLine("\nAfter calling replace:");
    Console.WriteLine(resourceStr.Replace("\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine));

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]